# Zigbee Over Air Download

Tags: zigbee

I am trying to implement zigbee OAD using CC2530.

Can anyone please tell me all the steps that are to be followed to implement OAD functionality..

P.S. 
I have gone through " over air download.pdf " and 
"developers note - Over air download.pdf" provided with zstack documents. but the ZOAD.exe fails to join network..

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I implemented OTA using MSP430/cc2520 and z-stack.
I chose it over OAD as the latest was a proprietary solution from TI.
When using OTA instead of OAD you use the OTA Server, which works good, enough at least for development.

Unless you need OAD, take a look to OTA, it seemed to me to better documented and, except for making my code to fit into the memory and using a non-supported external NV memory, the rest was pretty easy.

Hope this helps